# Is there a method for connecting the detected corners in python?

Tags: python, opencv, corner-detection

I want to connect the detected corners that belong to the same object draw like a triangle around that. the following is my code it works I just want to add this functionality.

```
image= cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
test=im
    
image = np.float32(image)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(image,2,3,0.04)
test[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255] 
cv2.imshow('dst',image)
```

Comment: Do you have any example image that you can post?

Comment: Post and image to some free hosting service and put the URL in a comment for us to use.  But if you have corners, you can draw lines between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cv2.line()` method to draw a line between two points. Here is the documentation shows you how to use this method:
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html